# How to query nested list in Mongo C# 2.2 driver with Linq?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

How to do aggregation query with Linq. I know there is a `AsQueryable()` interface. But it seems throwing errors when I do aggregations.

If I have a collection called `person` stores data like this:

```
  {
    "Name": "Punny",
    "Interests": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
```

and another collection called `interests` stores data like this:

```
  {
    "_id":1,
    "name":"music"
  },
  {
    "_id":2,
    "name":"read"
  }
```

I want to get something like this:

```
  {
    "Name": "Punny",
    "Interests": [
      "music",
      "read"
    ]
  }
```

How can I achieve this via Linq to with `AsQueryable`?
I tried this:

```
_context.People.AsQueryable()
    .Select(p => new
    {
      Name = p.Name,
      Interests = p.InterestingIds
       .Join(_context.Interests.AsQueryable(),
        per => per,
        i => i.Id,
        (per, i) => new {i.Name})
    }).ToList();
```

It throws a `System.NotSupportedException`

> System.NotSupportedException : Join of type System.Linq.Enumerable is not supported in the expression tree {document}{InterestingIds}.Join([FunnyMongoBlog.interest], per => per, i => i.Id, (per, i) => new <>f__AnonymousType1`1(Name = i.Name)).

I tried my self with a two trip to database:

```
      var person = _context.People.AsQueryable()
    .Single(p => p.Name == "Punny");
  var ids = person.InterestingIds;
  var query = _context.Interests.AsQueryable()
    .Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id)).ToList();
  var result = new
  {
    person.Name,
    Interest = query
  };
```

This is working but I wonder if we can do it with one trip so that the database could handle the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in aggregation framework, but I'd to suggest using power of subDocumnets in mongoDB and embed those elements fully in main document. In other words we need to switch from relational thinking to document thinking.

My suggested object shape:

```
{
    "Name" : "Punny",
    "Interests" : [{
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "music"
        }, {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "read"
        }
    ]
}
```

in c# code

```
class MyClass {
    public string Name;
    public List < Interest > Interests;
}

class Interest {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Now please find bson document needed for that transformation requested in question:

```
db.col.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$Interests"
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : "interests",
                localField : "Interests",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as : "interest"
            }
        }, {
            // now we need to reshape document
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                Name : 1,
                Interests : "$interest.name"
            }
        },
        //group documents back
        {
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    id : "$_id",
                    name : "$Name"
                },
                Interests : {
                    $push : "$Interests"
                }
            }
        }, {
            //final reshape
            _id : "$_id.id",
            Name : "$_id.name",
            Interests : 1
        }
    ])
```

and decide if embeding is worth a try :-)

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am thinking to query it with the new Linq syntax. Instead of using predefined BsonDocument. As far as I know there is a `AsQueryable()` interface then I can convert Linq into the query.

Comment: go ahead with that - I just included this query to show you **huge weakness** of your document design....